# Run all jQuery/prototype document.ready functions manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I use AJAX to load some content to the page, and that content has some jQuery(document).ready() code in it. I need for the stuff in the ready function to execute, but I cannot modify the actual code, but only use what's been provided by server via AJAX.

How to trigger those functions in jQuery 1.4+ / Prototype?

Basically, what I need to do is to execute an inline javascript code from a HTML response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an **eval(code)** of the code that comes from another source. When using Ajax you have to specify what kind of output are you expecting (dataType for jQuery Ajax call). This can be xml, json, script, or html. Unless you are doing JsonP and you import a script the other datatypes are basically text and you need to eval them in order to execute them. Once you eval() them the functions from the other source will be available in your global environment.

Comment: The content I get from server is html, with js in it, so eval() would trigger a syntax error?
I need to execute inline javascript from a html response. The source is read-only.

Comment: then try to get the content with curl and echo it in php generating a page that contains your code and the other code, maybe even parse it just to get only the js code. But this is not ajax anymore.

Comment: The jQuery help for `dataType: html` says "included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM."

Comment: then it should work directly. check your code for other errors.

Comment: It seems that when you try to insert filtered response (filtered using `find()`), eval doesn't work. So, this works:
`mediaContainer.html(jQuery(response));`
but this doesn't:
`mediaContainer.html(jQuery(response).find('div'));`
although 'div' contains the JS code

Comment: in my opinion, if you have to resort to this kind of programming something is wrong in the architecture. Try to rethink the whole process, it will be better for you in the long term to create clean and maintainable code.

Comment: Code is Magento, response being parsed is product controller response, that contains media html template file, that again contains prototype gallery trigger, and people often put their own gallery triggers in that PHTML file. So I need to fire off that triggers. Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: why am I not surprised to hear this things about Magento?